# not able to set Brightness when app enter in Background, can any one have any idea about it?

Tags: ios, swift, background, application-lifecycle, screen-brightness

code not working in did enter in background method.

```
 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)

    }
```

Comment: even i am already tried with delay but still not working.

Comment: You can't. When an app enters the background it is no longer able to change the screen brightness.

Comment: 1. Conceptually, if your app goes into background, it wont be visible, so why is it trying to change UI (brightness)? 2. Have you tried it doing this in `applicationWillResignActive` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this in the applicationWillResignActive and seems to achieve what you are looking for. Not sure if this is recommended behaviour though.

Here are my methods from AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UIScreen.main.brightness = 1.0;
        return true
    }



func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

         UIScreen.main.brightness = 0.5
    }
```

Comment: it's working in applicationWillResignActive but not working in DidEnterInBackground . can you check un DidEnterInBackground at Your side ?

Comment: Any reason why you want this to happen in DidEnterInBackground

Comment: my app functionality is in low brightness so when user go in other app so it should be not go with low brightness. i.e. i want to change brightness when user enter in backround mode.

Comment: The above code doesn't work in your case ? When the user navigates to another app, the brightness does change right ?

Comment: yes, i want to change brightness when user navigate to other app.

Comment: That is happening right ? Launch the aapp -> Brightness becomes 1, send app to background/Switch to another app -> brightness becomes .5. I just checked ...